# react native expo image picker errors

Tags: reactjs, expo, native

When I try add plugin (`"plugins": [ [ "expo-image-picker", { "cameraPermission": "The app accesses your camera to let you add new places" } ] ]`) I get an error[plugin error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNxut.jpg)

then I'm trying to instal expo "expo install expo-image-picker" but another error showing up that [cannot find module error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMIiF.jpg) so I stuck.. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I run "npm install expo-image-picker" instead of "expo install expo image picker" then problem has solved

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDTQ5.png)

i have get it.

because of use react native firebase,  my project work on custom native code model

this is my step:

1. npx expo install  expo-image-picker
2. config app.json  plugins  (get error on runtime)
3. eas build --profile development --platform android (build a local version)
4. eas build:run -p android (install to qemu-system ;select build version ID)
5. although  not found error in app.json  but it work

[it's working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc7XK.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).